# make: Wl,-z,now: Command not found

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm getting this error while linking a C++ code.
I'm using g++ cross compiler for arm and building it on a Ubuntu machine.
Do I have to pass any flags or include some library?

Comment: What is the command you're issuing?

Comment: Can we see the make file? Some context for the error would help as well.

Comment: I am using '-Wl,-z,now' for ldflags.

Comment: Without seeing the make rule or even an example of the command make is running we can't help.  However, based on this error I'd say that you're missing the actual compiler name in the command line, so make is trying to run the first argument as a command.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks, the compiler name was missing. I set it and it worked.
As you said it was executing Wl,-z,now as command.